# Неправильная работа оператора if

Tags: python, access, база-данных, firebird, sql

Я написал следующие функции по переносу данных из Access в Firebird

```
def getFirebirdFieldNames(firebird_cursor, tablename):
    firebird_cursor.execute('select rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name=\'%s\' order by rdb$field_position' % (tablename,))
    field_names = list()
    for c in firebird_cursor.fetchall():
        field_names.append(c[0])
    return field_names

def FirebirdDatetime(dt):
    return '\'%s.%s.%s\'' % (str(dt.day).rjust(2,'0'),
                                   str(dt.month).rjust(2,'0'),
                                   str(dt.year).rjust(4,'0'))

def SelectFromAccessTable(tablename):
    return 'select * from [' + tablename+']'

def InsertToFirebirdTable(tablename, row):
    values=''
    #values=values.encode('cp1251', 'replace')
#   copyrow=[]
#   print type(values)
    for i in range(len(row)):
        #print row[i]
        #print type(row[i])
        #temp=''
        if (i<len(row)-1):
                if type(row[i]) == int:
                    temp = str(row[i])
                else:
                    if type(row[i]) == str:
                        temp = '\'%s\'' % (row[i],)
                    else:
                        if type(row[i]) == datetime.datetime:
                            temp =FirebirdDatetime(row[i])
                        else:
                            if type(row[i]) == decimal.Decimal:
                                temp = str(row[i])
                            else:
                                if row[i]==None:
                                    temp='null'
                values+=temp+', '                 
        else:
                if type(row[i]) == int:
                    temp = str(row[i])
                else:
                    if type(row[i]) == str:
                        temp = '\'%s\'' % (row[i],)
                    else:
                        if type(row[i]) == datetime.datetime:
                            temp =FirebirdDatetime(row[i])
                        else:
                            if type(row[i]) == decimal.Decimal:
                                temp = str(row[i])
                            else:
                                if row[i]==None:
                                    temp='null'
                values+=temp
        print temp
    return 'insert into '+tablename+' values ('+values+')'

def AccessToFirebird(accesstablename, firebirdtablename, accesscursor, firebirdcursor):
    SelectSql=SelectFromAccessTable(accesstablename)
    for row in accesscursor.execute(SelectSql):
        InsertSql=InsertToFirebirdTable(firebirdtablename, row)
        InsertSql=InsertSql
        print InsertSql
        firebirdcursor.execute(InsertSql)
```

При вызове функции `AccessToFirebird` в основном модуле вызывается функция `InsertToFirebirdTable`, в которой происходит вывод на экран формируемых `insert` запросов. Как видно из нижеприведенного вывода `temp` присваивается `row[0]` и в дальнейшем не изменяется, что противоречит логике программы (в цикле происходит обход всего `row` и в результате должен получиться запрос вставки со всеми передаваемыми значениями). Почему так происходит и как сделать, чтобы результат соответствовал цели? Привожу вывод формируемых запросов (база данных Борей в Access)

```
1
1
1
1
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
insert into CLIENTS values (1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
2
2
2
2
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
insert into CLIENTS values (2, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
3
3
3
3
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
insert into CLIENTS values (3, 3, 3, 3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
4
4
4
4
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
insert into CLIENTS values (4, 4, 4, 4, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

Comment: Все очень понятно и читабельно. Ожидайте ответ в течении года

Comment: это вобще огонь!

долго вставлял сюда код?

Comment: @moden и @Shrek у меня только вывод формируемых запросов большой (и то можно читать не все - а только первые 4 запроса, чтобы понять что происходит).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые переносимые данные были типа `unicode`, а их обработка была не предусмотрена в `if`, поэтому `temp` сохраняло свое значение (не присваивалось новое).